# node-gyp build error 'msbuild failed with error code 1'

Tags: node.js, msbuild, npm, node-gyp

I am getting this error while I try to run

```
node-gyp build

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Users\Ramya\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Users\\Ramya\\AppDat
a\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd f:\ontology\api\ontoapi\example\node_modules
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

i already have set `--msvs_verion=2013`. I already have set path for python 2.7 also. I am using Windows 8.1, nodejs - 0.12.2, npm- 2.7.4, node-gyp- 1.0.3

Comment: do you have visual studio installed?

Comment: yes. I have visual studio 2012 installed

Comment: if I am not mistaken, --msvs_verion=2013 for msvs 2012??

Comment: You may follow the thread https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/168

Comment: I get this when I install msvs_version=2012 
'npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 No README data
npm WARN package.json node-java@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json node-java@1.0.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json path@0.11.14 path is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@1.0.3 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-inspector@0.9.2 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global npm@2.8.3 should be installed with -g'

Comment: but if it builds it is fine. You may ignore warnings.

Comment: I still have the same msbuild error